# Count number of ways player 1 can win in a 2 player game

Tags: algorithm

I came across this following question,

2 players play a game. In each turn both players receive points in the range -x to +x (both included). Player 1 starts from score p1 and player 2 starts from score p2. If they play a total of k turns, find the total number of ways in which player 1 can win the game i.e at the end of k turns, player 1 has more points than player 2.

So in short my understanding is that we need to find total number of combination set of points for player1 and player2 such that (sum of points set of player 1)-(sum of points set of player 2) >= p2-p1+1

I am not sure how to tackle this problem. Please suggest an approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this recursively.  Using your variables, let's look at the cases:.  Let

```
score_range = [-x : x]
```

Call the function `win_count`

**Base case, k==1**

if `k == 1`, there is one turn to go.  The score difference is p2-p1.  If player 2 scores `n2` points in this round, then player 1 needs to finish with at least `(p2 + n2) - p1 + 1` points this round.  Now, how many combinations of that are available with `p1, p2 in score_range` ?  You can compute that directly from the given integers.

Return that count as the functional value.

**Recursion case, k > 1**

Walk through all of the possible scores for this round.  Recur to count possibilities for the remainder of the game.

```
count = 0
for n1 in score_range
    for n2 in score_range
        count += win_count(p1+n1, p2+n2, k-1, x)
```

Can you take it from there?

Comment: There must be a dp formulation for this right? For instance instead of -x to +x, we could also use 0 to 2x as our range and the final answer should still be the same. I'm not exactly sure what what states to consider though. Will it be a 3d array, one dimension for the round, one each for scores of player 1 and 2?

Comment: Good work -- of course there's a DP improvement.  Don't bother to build your own; just use the `@memoize` decorator (you can look up the package).  There are four parameters to the function, but one is constant, so there will be three active keys for the memoization: `p1, p2, k`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution!